# How to use toupper() on a pointer to a string?

Tags: c, pointers, toupper

I have tried the following: `*string = toupper(*string);`

This only made the first char of the string pointer to by the pointer upper case. I want all the chars pointer to by *pointer to be in uppercase. Anyway I can do this?

Comment: You've got an approach that works for a single character in the string.   Logic would suggest using a loop to apply the same approach to every character in the string.    Also, be aware that the argument and return value of `toupper()` is of type `int`, not `char`.

Comment: C does not have a string type. It is just a sequence of `char`. Iteration statements (aka loops) are explßained in every book/tutorial about programming in general and C in special.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as it is shown below

```
char s[] = "hello world";

for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p ) *p = toupper( ( unsigned char )*p );
```

Take into account that you may not change string literals. String literals are immutable. If you write for example in the above code

```
char *s = "hello world";
```

instead of

```
char s[] = "hello world";
```

then the program behaviour will be undefined.

Comment: Nice `( unsigned char )` detail and caution about `char *s = "hello world";`

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through every character like this

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; string[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    string[i] = toupper((unsigned char) string[i]);
```

The behaviour you are observing is because `*` dereferences the pointer, and since you are dereferencing the pointer without incrementing it, you are just setting the first element of the sequence of characters.

The `*` operator works on a pointer in the following way: `*(pointer + offset)` is equivalent to `pointer[offset]`. So `*string = toupper(*string)` is equivalent to

```
string[0] = toupper(string[0]);
```